# How to a clickable element while still using "position:absolute"?

Tags: css

On desktop (or big screens) my logo is clickable.

But on mobile screens, my logo isn't clickable.

I think it is because of the position:absolute of the logo.

But I need to keep that because otherwise, the menu isn't centered anymore on desktop screens.

I've made a codepen so you can see it live : codepen.io/philiposbgos/pen/vYQNWdo

I've tried many other ways to center it (flex box, flex grow, text-align center, etc.) but none of them kept my menu centered on desktop excepted position:absolute.

So in order to keep my logo clickable on mobiles, I've tried to set my .logo class to a media query and give it a relative position.

But it still didn't work.

I really don't understand what is happening. I've been on it since this morning and can't find a way to keep the design as it is and just make my logo clickable on mobiles screen.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logo is covered by other elements at some dimensions. Add `z-index:1;` to the .logo selector to position it on top of the other elements.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

header {
  background-color: #2529D8;
  height: 70px;
  padding-top: 4px;
  padding-bottom: 4px;
}

.menu {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 960px;
  padding: 0 20px;  
  position: relative;
  margin:auto;
}
.menu-items {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease;
}
.menu li {
  margin: 10px 10px;
}

.menu a {
  color: white;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.menu a:hover {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.hamburger-menu {
  display: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

.hamburger-line {
  width: 20px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 4px 0;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease;
}

#menu-toggle {
  display: none;
}

#menu-toggle:checked ~ .menu-items {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: fixed;
  top: 68px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #2529D8;
  padding: 20px;
  z-index: 1;
  transform: translateX(0%);
}

#menu-toggle:checked ~ .hamburger-menu .hamburger-line:nth-child(2) {
  opacity: 0;
}

#menu-toggle:checked ~ .hamburger-menu .hamburger-line:nth-child(1) {
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-6px, 6px);
}

#menu-toggle:checked ~ .hamburger-menu .hamburger-line:nth-child(3) {
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-6px, -6px);
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .menu {
    justify-content: flex-end;
    margin-right:30px;
  }

  .menu-items {
    display: none;
  }

  .hamburger-menu {
    display: block;
    
  }
}

.logo {
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  margin-left: 45px;
  flex-grow: 1;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 172px;
  height: 64px;
  z-index:1;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <a href="https://www.gamingchairmaster.com">
      <img src="https://www.gamingchairmaster.com/wp-content/uploads/gamingchairs.png" alt="Logo" class="logo" />
    </a>
    <nav class="menu"> 
      <input type="checkbox" id="menu-toggle" />
      <label for="menu-toggle" class="hamburger-menu">
        <div class="hamburger-line"></div>
        <div class="hamburger-line"></div>
        <div class="hamburger-line"></div>
      </label>
      <ul class="menu-items">
        <li><a href="https://www.gamingchairmaster.com/reviews/">Reviews</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://www.gamingchairmaster.com/guides/">Guides</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
```